# Method of a class not giving expected result

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I wrote the following 3 pieces of code:

Driver.java:

```
package herds;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        organism Wolf = new organism(1,2);
        System.out.println(Wolf.toString());
        Wolf.move(1,2);
        System.out.println(Wolf.toString());
        
        dog Bobby = new dog(0,3,"Bobby");
        System.out.println(Bobby.bark());
        System.out.println(Bobby.toString());
        Bobby.move(0, 1);
        System.out.println(Bobby.toString());
    }
}
```

organism.java

```
package herds;

public class organism {
    int x; 
    int y;
    
    public organism(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "x: " + this.x + ";" + "y: " + this.y;           
    }

    public void move(int dx, int dy) {
        this.x = this.x + dx;
        this.y = this.y + dy;
    }
}
```

dog.java:

```
package herds;

public class dog extends organism {
    int x; 
    int y;
    String name;
    
    public dog(int x, int y, String name) {
        super(x, y);
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String bark() {
        return this.name +  " says Woof";
    }
    
    @Override
    public void move(int dx, int dy) {
        this.x = dx;
        this.y = dy;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the output of the Driver file. Specifically, it gives the following as output:

```
x: 1;y: 2
x: 2;y: 4
Bobby says Woof
x: 0;y: 3
x: 0;y: 3
```

I don't understand why the final line would be `x: 0;y: 3`, and not `x: 0;y: 1`, because by the definition of the move method for the dog class, `this.x = 0` and `this.y = 1`. So why would `x: 0` and `y: 3` after this method is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are hiding `x` and `y` in the class `dog`.
2. When you update them in the `move` method, you update them in the `dog` class.
3. But the `toString` method prints from the `organism` class.

Fix:

Just remove `x` and `y` from the `dog` class.  You may need to add `protected` to their definition in the `organism` class.  (Also remove the `this` from `move` in the `dog` class.  Seriously I don't like the style of always adding `this` to instance variables.)

```
public class dog extends organism {
    //int x; 
    //int y;
    String name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So how should I have written this, in order to print x:0 and y: 1?

Comment: .... __Just remove the `x` and `y` from the `dog` class__.